# Query from logic apps is not searching across all partitions in CosmosDB when the partition key value field is empty

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

The query from logic apps is not searching across all partitions in CosmosDB when the partition key value field is empty. When the exact same query is run from data explorer all partitions are queried and all expected data is returned. When the query is run from logic apps using log analytics I can see that a query is only being run for 1 partition range, and not all the expected results are returned. (some are, from the partitions that were hit)

From the docs for partition key value: *Value must be provided according to its type ("string", 42, 0.5). If empty, all partitions will be used to search for documents.*

Expected function would be logic apps Query documents V5 connector to return the same results from a SQL query as run in CosmosDB data explorer
[image]

Comment: There is a new Logic Apps connector for the Standard Plan, is this something you could try? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQLzXfCU6bY&ab_channel=AzureCosmosDB

Comment: This connector is the one I am using.

Comment: Can you share an screenshot or code definition of the Logic App Query operation with the parameters you are passing? When I look at the "Query Items" operation for the Standard Plan connector, I don't see any Partition Key parameter.

Comment: I've edited the main post to include the connector

Comment: "Query documents V5" doesn't look like the Connector in the video in my previous comment. Is there a chance you can try that other connector?

Comment: The newer connector says "Query items" (not documents) and has no Partition Key parameter.

Comment: Hi @MatiasQuaranta, I tried to use the newer connector and still had the same problems.

Comment: Hi Matias, I found the issue due to one of your other responses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760389/azure-cosmosdb-rest-api-omits-results-that-data-explorer-returns 
It's to do with the continuation token

Comment: Interesting! Seems like the problem then is that you needed to use the continuation to fetch the next pages? Share the answer to your questions to help others in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query documents v5 can return an empty array in response to a query in CosmosDB, but the intended behaviour is for the user to check if the response has a continuation token, implying the query should be run again, passing in the continuation token as a header for the new request. This needs to be done to retrieve all the data.

Copy pasting a comment from another thread:

When executing queries using the REST API, make sure you are consuming and verifying the x-ms-continuation header. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-response-headers

You can iterate (send more requests) until the Continuation Token is not being returned in the response.